# Map Active Directory Custom Properties with Office365

Tags: office-365, active-directory, custom-properties

my company offers support to one of our clients and they use Office365.

The question is that they wanted to map custom properties from their Active Directory to Office365, so they could create custom properties at "User Profile Manager"

I searched on a few sites including Microsoft blogs and the most users told me that it is impossible to do at Office365. If we look in one of the properties in "User Profile Properties" we can see that there is a field (dropdown) for adding a new mapping but this field is empty. This field is the data connection but on Office365 there is no connection so I could select.

I wanted to know if is really possible to map active directory custom properties with Office365. We know our client already configured their Active Directory with Office365 so they can synchronize.

We used to do these things on a Sharepoint Server installation (On-Premisse) but in Office365 we can't.

Does anyone can give me a help?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot change the mappings to AD or create new mappings in SharePoint Online. SharePoint Online follows the same default set of mapped AD attributes that on-prem SharePoint uses:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh147510.aspx

Azure AD Connect tool has improved a lot and now lets you sync custom AD attributes with Azure AD (it used to only sync a fixed set of attributes), but unfortunately even though those attributes are available in the cloud directory, SharePoint Online is unable to leverage them via User Profile Sync.

Since you cannot add/change mappings, the only option currently available is to write your own process or scheduled task to read information from local AD or Azure AD, and do a bulk User Profile sync. There is an excellent sample available as part of the Office Patterns and Practices:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.BulkUserProfileUpdater